# Using Tornado and mysql with Python 3x

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tornado

Tornado framework is compatible with Python 3, but it uses the mysqldb package which from what I've read is not compatible with Python 3.

Will this present any issues when working with my mysql database? If so, is there a workaround? I'd be open to using another framework that is more friendly to Python 3, but I'm committed to sticking with Python 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues, as Tornado has no dependencies on a particular client; the wrapper is included for your convenience. You can get a working py3 version of python-mysqldb on [Golhke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python). Since you can use any valid Python code in the handlers, you can also use any other library (like [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/)), you just won't be able to use Tornado's wrapper functions.